# Meshlab crashes when applying filter

Tags: filter, meshlab

I installed Meshlab from source code using this [comment](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/74#issuecomment-279254296). But the application crashes when I am trying to apply the filter Screened Poisson surface Reconstruction with the error

error: ./meshlab: symbol lookup error: /home/badri/Documents/MESHLAB/meshlab/src/distrib/plugins/libfilter_screened_poisson.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs

I tried all the solutions described in the issues section of Meshlab's GitHub repo but couldn't make it work. 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

other info:
filter_screen_poisson.xml

```
<FILTER filterFunction="screenedPoissonSurfaceReconstruction" 
filterName="Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction" 
filterPre="MM_NONE" filterRasterArity="SingleRaster" 
filterClass="Remeshing" filterPost="MM_VERTNUMBER | MM_FACENUMBER" 
filterArity="Variable" filterIsInterruptible="true">
```

extra added lines to filter_screened_poisson.pro as suggested fixes from issues, but they don't seem to work for me.

```
linux:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp -lgomp
linux:QMAKE_POST_LINK = "cp "$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/$$TARGET".xml 
../../distrib/plugins/"$$TARGET".xml; cd ../../distrib/plugins/ ;ln -s 
"$$TARGET".xml lib"$$TARGET".xml"
```

and rest of the file is the same.

Is there something I have missed or did wrong? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution. The additions were correct and sufficient.
I solved my issue by initially unmaking(i.e., go to meshlab/src/ then run make clean) and again just run make.